# optimize attribute value on a cell grid

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have been trying to design an algorithm for a mod of the game "Minecraft" called "Nuclearcraft". More specifically, an algorithm to optimize the cooling value of a fission reactor.

This fission reactor is simply a cuboid with at least one reactor cell inside, now, depending on how many you have connecting to each other either through moderator blocks or directly, it geometrically increases the heat produced, and intuitively, if the reactors exceeds his top temperature it explodes.

What the algorithm should do is when given a .txt document with my reactor layout in a simple layered grid, for example:

```
    101
    000
    101

    202
    000
    202

    101
    000
    101
```

Where 0 is air or an empty space, 1 is a reactor cell, and 2 is a moderator block.
it should attempt to permutate betwen available coolers inside that grid in empty spaces, there are different kinds of coolers and each has their own rules and different heat rates(since it's cooling heat rate is a negative value). Cooling value is static depending on type of cooler independednt of actual placement, the only rules determine if it works or not so there is no optimal placement for an individual type of cooler just valid ones.

The problem lies in the logic used, a simple permutation descending from the cooler with the most cooling rate and checking against it's rules. That works for the first iteration, and for subsequent ones. but i am not just trying to find a solution but the one with the most cooling rate, what i mean is that one cooler in 'X,Y,Z' might cool less than two coolers with specific rules on almost the same space, which is another problem in itself, ideally the cube should not have empty spaces.

As for coding the different cooler block types,  i thought of adding them as objects with the cooling values as attributes and each with their own validate function with returns either true or false if it can be placed or not given the block grid and coordinates.
Another factor is the possibility to avoid using certain types of coolers which require rarer materials after i get a working one, in the mod some coolers have similar rules to each other just with a superior cooling rate depending on the rarity of the material used.

Comment: I've played Minecraft Mods that have reactors, and found this question by searching new questions related to Minecraft. And I still don't follow what you are trying to say in the text portion of the question. "That works for the first iteration" What works? What result? can you (maybe graphically) show what you did?

Also you havn't actually got any code here. That's usually a good sign that it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

What is your overall goal? Is this for the simulation of the reactor? or are you trying to 'crack' your own optimum strategy for some reason?

Comment: Re-reading the question, it sounds like it might not be your own mod, and that you are indeed trying to 'crack' the optimum strategy of block placements.